# Get a request parameter key-value in fasthttp

Tags: http, url, go, fasthttp

http://127.0.0.1:8080/x?haha=1

I want to get something like `ctx.QueryArgs().Get("haha")`

is it possible in golang's `fasthttp` package?

Comment: By golang's fasthttp you mean [this](https://github.com/valyala/fasthttp) ?

Comment: @Sridhar sure yes.

Comment: `haha := ctx.QueryArgs().GetUintOrZero("haha")` - https://godoc.org/github.com/valyala/fasthttp#RequestCtx.QueryArgs

Comment: @MartinGallagher thanks. found it! It's the `Peek()` method.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found it

```
ctx.QueryArgs().Peek("haha")
```

The naming choice is unexpected.

Answer (score 4):

use Peek and PeekMulti

```
?haha=1
ctx.QueryArgs().Peek("haha")

?haha=1&haha=2
ctx.QueryArgs().PeekMulti("haha")
```

Some useful methods are declared here:
https://github.com/valyala/fasthttp/blob/a1cfe58ca86648c6701f1cb7e8b1587348dd5b9f/args.go#L245

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve a custom **GET, POST PUT** parameter using *FormValue* method:
 - **GET** (Query String such as ?user=a&pass=b);
 - **POST, PUT** body

Literally, from the documentation:

*FormValue returns form value associated with the given key.*

The *value is searched* in the following places:

- Query string;
- POST or PUT body.

There are more fine-grained methods for obtaining form values:

- *QueryArgs* for obtaining values from query string.
- *PostArgs* for obtaining values from POST or PUT body.
- *MultipartForm* for obtaining values from multipart form.
- *FormFile* for obtaining uploaded files.

```golang
token = string(ctx.FormValue("token"))
```

Documentation:
https://godoc.org/github.com/valyala/fasthttp#RequestCtx.FormValue

Answer (score 0):

---

Another option while you don't have the ctx but have `ctx.Request` is this:

```
// somewhere
req := &ctx.Request
.
.
.
// somewhere else
req.URI().QueryArgs().Peek("somekey")
```