# Define parameters as param request instad of endpoint url in fasthttprouter

Tags: http, go, server, fasthttp

I am using golang´s fasthttprouter and have followed the examples and defined a router like this:

```
router.GET("/customer/account/detail/:accountId", myHandler.customerAccountDetailHandler)
```

Then I call to my service as `http://locahost:9296/customer/account/detail/2`

But I realised that I do not want to have the parameters as part of the endpoint , I rather prefer to use normal parameters by calling my service like this:

```
http://locahost:9296/customer/account/detail?accountId=2&sort=1
```

Is it possible to be done with fasthttprouter? How?

Thanks in advance
J

Answer (score 0):

The query parameter should be accessible from the request context.
You should have a handler that takes a `*fasthttp.RequestCtx` argument. This `RequestCtx` can access the URI and the query params on that URI. That should look something like this:

```
ctx.URI().QueryArgs().Peek("accountId")
```

You'll have to update your handler to use this query parameter instead of the route param you were previously using. The same would also apply for the `sort` param.

Also, your router would have to be updated to route `/customer/account/detail` to your updated handler (i.e. you'll want to remove `/:accountId` from your route).

Comment: So, basically I should stop using the fasthttprouter package and use the default fasthttp handlers. Am I right?

Comment: @antonof I don't think you need to change any packages to get this working. You only need to change the behaviour of `myHandler.customerAccountDetailHandler` to extract the `accountId` from the query param using the code snippet above and update the router to `router.GET("/customer/account/detail", myHandler.customerAccountDetailHandler)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions is similar to this one:
[Get a request parameter key-value in fasthttp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39265978/9361998)

You can retrieve the parameters of the request in this way:

```golang
token = string(ctx.FormValue("token"))
```

Have a look at my complete response here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57740178/9361998

Documentation: https://godoc.org/github.com/valyala/fasthttp#RequestCtx.FormValue